# .htaccess Always hide a certain subdirectory from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hide a subdirectory from the URL with **.htaccess**. I've got a PHP script which is executed everytime a client enters the website. It's `index.php` in root Apache directory. This script determines the **language** to use in the website and redirects to the target directory. English is my default language so what I need **"en"** directory to be hidden in the URL and at the same time redirect all the URL requests from root directory to **"en"** folder so they don't produce a 404 HTTP error. I partially achieved this with the following lines:

```
#Remove en/ directory from URL
RewriteRule ^$ en/

#Forward all the requests to en/ directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1
```

When requests are forwarded to **"en"** directory this is displayed again in the URL. This would be the flow:

- User types: http://domain.com
- index.php Redirects to http://domain.com/en because that's the detected language
- .htaccess Rule hides /en directory, leaving the URL http://domain.com
- Client types http://domain.com/panel to access their user panel
- .htaccess Redirects to http://domain.com/en/panel

How can I remove **"en"** directory leaving the URL http://domain.com/panel after the last action in the list? Is there a better way to manage this behavior?

Current rules:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ en/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!en/).*)$ en/$1 [L,NC]

#Prevent direct access to PHP Scripts
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]

#Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

#Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash if public/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]

#Prevent direct access to PHP Scripts
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ en/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!en/).*)$ en/$1 [L,NC]
```

Clear your browser cache and test your flows.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior as before. Note: .htaccess file is located in root directory.

Comment: Just added the full .htaccess

Comment: I'm getting the same. I made sure I cleared the cache. Extra note: while trying to access other directory that is not "en" I'm getting 404 error. For example: http://domain.com/es gives 404 error ("es" directory exists the same as "en")

Comment: "es" directory error was corrected. I'm still getting the same behavior I had before. When I enter "domain.com" no 301/302 redirects are registered. When I enter "domain.com/panel" a 301 redirect is registered with direction http://domain.com/panel, with Initiator as "other" and next HTTP code is 200 with address http://domain.com/en/panel, Initiator "http://domain.com/panel"

Comment: Original URL `http://domain.com/panel`
Redirected URL `http://domain.com/en/panel` Thanks for your patience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135324/discussion-between-anubhava-and-protectedvoid).